# Error: write after end on Meteor app

Tags: node.js, meteor, modulus.io

I have today for the first time our new meteor app on modulus uploaded. When I tried to test them, the app crash with the error :

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:167:12)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:212:5)
    at Socket.write (net.js:626:40)
    at [object Object].Connection.write (/mnt/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:502:58)
    at /mnt/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:204:16
    at executeScram (/mnt/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/scram.js:176:5)
    at /mnt/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/auth/scram.js:281:7
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

The app tried three times to restart. The app ran normally for the fourth time. I could test everything and it worked. After about 10 minutes, the app crashed again with the same error message. From then on always randomly. What can I do?

**UPDATE**

My packages:

```
aaronroberson:ng-mask                                 3.0.16  AngularJS input masks packaged for meteor
accounts-base                                         1.2.14  A user account system
accounts-password                                     1.3.1  Password support for accounts
alanning:roles                                        1.2.15  Authorization package for Meteor
aldeed:simple-schema                                  1.5.3  A simple schema validation object with reactivity. Used by collection2 a...
alisalaah:jquery-contextmenu                          1.6.6  JQuery ContextMenu by Rodney Rehm
altapp:recaptcha                                      2.0.1  Form bot protection for Meteor.
angular-meteor-auth                                   1.0.3* Angular-Meteor authentication module
angular-with-blaze                                    1.3.11  Everything you need to use both AngularJS and Blaze templates in your M...
angular:angular-animate                               1.5.3_1  AngularJS (official) release. For full solution: http://angular-meteor...
angular:angular-material                              1.0.6  Google Material design written for AngularJs (official repo)
angularui:angular-ui-router                           0.2.15  angular-ui-router (official): Flexible routing with nested views in Ang...
bevanhunt:leaflet                                     2.0.1* leaflet - mobile-friendly maps.
check                                                 1.2.4  Check whether a value matches a pattern
dandv:jquery-rateit                                   1.0.22_2  RateIt - a modern, mobile-friendly, jQuery (star) rating plugin
ecmascript                                            0.5.9  Compiler plugin that supports ES2015+ in all .js files
edgee:slingshot                                       0.7.1  Directly post files to cloud storage services, such as AWS-S3.
ejson                                                 1.0.13  Extended and Extensible JSON library
email                                                 1.1.18  Send email messages
erasaur:meteor-lodash                                 4.0.0  Wrapper for Lo-Dash v4.0.0
erasaur:server-session                                0.0.5  Meteor Server-side Sessions, similar to the typical Client Session
es5-shim                                              4.6.15  Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAScript 5 support
fortawesome:fontawesome                               4.6.3* Font Awesome (official): 500+ scalable vector icons, customizable via CS...
gfk:mediator                                          1.0.0  Adds a mediator to your application
gromo:jquery.scrollbar                                0.0.1  Cross-browser CSS customizable scrollbar with advanced features.
harrison:papa-parse                                   1.1.1  A powerful, in-browser CSV parser for big boys and girls
http                                                  1.2.10  Make HTTP calls to remote servers
jonblum:jquery-cropper                                2.3.0  Fengyuan Chen's terrific jQuery plugin for cropping/zooming/rotating ima...
lucavandro:angular-moment-with-locales                0.10.3  Angular-Meteor directive and filters for Moment.JS with locales
matb33:collection-hooks                               0.8.4  Extends Mongo.Collection with before/after hooks for insert/update/remov...
matthieuh:angular-local-storage                       0.2.2  Angular module that gives you access to the browsers local storage with ...
maxkferg:temp                                         1.0.0  Create tracked temporary files on the server
mdg:validated-method                                  1.1.0  A simple wrapper for Meteor.methods
meteor-base                                           1.0.4  Packages that every Meteor app needs
meteorhacks:kadira                                    2.30.0* Performance Monitoring for Meteor
meteorhacks:meteor-down                               1.1.2  Load Testing Framework for Meteor
meteorhacks:npm                                       1.5.0  Use npm modules with your Meteor App
meteorhacks:sikka                                     1.0.1  Sikka - A Firewall for Meteor Apps
mobile-experience                                     1.0.4  Packages for a great mobile user experience
mongo                                                 1.1.14  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP
mrt:external-file-loader                              0.1.4  The External File Loader package helps easily load external js, css and ...
nimble:restivus                                       0.8.11  Create authenticated REST APIs in Meteor 0.9+ via HTTP/HTTPS. Setup CRU...
npm-container                                         1.2.0+ Contains all your npm dependencies
pacozaa:angular-material-data-table                   0.9.9  Material Design Data Table for Angular Material
pdiniz:canvas-to-blob                                 0.0.2  Simple wrapper around the blueimp's JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob package
peerlibrary:aws-sdk                                   2.4.9_1  SDK for AWS services including Amazon S3, Amazon EC2, DynamoDB, and Am...
perak:joins                                           1.0.8  Generic collection joins for Meteor
percolate:synced-cron                                 1.3.2  Allows you to define and run scheduled jobs across multiple servers.
planettraining:angular-translate                      2.10.0  Angular Translate
planettraining:angular-translate-loader-static-files  2.10.0  Angular Translate
practicalmeteor:chai                                  2.1.0_1  The Chai Assertion Library, v2.1.0
practicalmeteor:mocha                                 2.4.5_6  Write package tests with mocha and run them in the browser or from the...
random                                                1.0.10  Random number generator and utilities
reactive-var                                          1.0.11  Reactive variable
rzymek:moment-locale-de                               2.14.1  Moment.js de locale. Companion package for rzymek:moment
sathriawan:angular-timer                              1.3.5_3  Angular-Timer : A simple AngularJS directive demonstrating re-usabilit...
shell-server                                          0.2.1  Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command.
standard-minifier-css                                 1.3.2  Standard css minifier used with Meteor apps by default.
standard-minifier-js                                  1.2.1  Standard javascript minifiers used with Meteor apps by default.
tracker                                               1.1.1  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks
undeadlol1:angular-filter-count-to                    1.0.0  Angular directive to animate counting to a number (by sparkalow)
urigo:angular-blaze-template                          0.3.0  Include Blaze templates in your angular-meteor application.
urigo:angular-ui-router                               0.7.0  urigo:angular-ui-router, adds the ability to use Blaze templates with ui...
veekungx:sc-date-time                                 1.1.6  A Date-Time picker based on Googles Material Design Spec http://simeonc....
vinaynb:angular-loading-bar
```

Comment: What were you doing at the time? Is it a problem with your proxy?

Comment: Things like, login, logout, navigate through the app. It also does not happen with a special function, just random. Maybe it is at a packet, I have now updated the post. What could be the problem with the proxy? It's a hoster, or I understand something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 10 days I finally found the solution. After I deleted certain packages and reinstalled them, I checked the environment variables. Here was the environment variable:

`MONGO_URL: mongodb://<username>:<password>@shard1:15689,shard2:15689/myDB`

This I changed to

`MONGO_URL: mongodb://<username>:<password>@shard1:15689/myDB`.

That solved the problem.